# Ruby small refactoring

Tags: ruby

I am making console app and user have to choose difficulty

```
def set_difficulty
  puts 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard'
  difficulty = user_input

  if (difficulty) == 'easy'
    @hints = 2
    @attempts = 15
  elsif (difficulty) == 'normal'
    @hints = 1
    @attempts = 10
  elsif (difficulty) == 'hard'
    @hints = 1
    @attempts = 5
  else
    puts 'Wrong input'
    set_difficulty
  end
end
```

Is there any way to make this method smaller but easy to read and understand

Comment: What's wrong with it now? (Unrelated, but the parens around `difficulty` are unnecessary and awkward.)

Comment: I'd use a loop instead of the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `case` block instead of `elif`:

```
def set_difficulty
  puts 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard'
  
  case user_input 
  when  'easy'
    @hints = 2
    @attempts = 15
  when 'normal'
    @hints = 1
    @attempts = 10
  when 'hard'
    @hints = 1
    @attempts = 5
  else
    puts 'Wrong input'
    set_difficulty
  end
end
```

Or a hash with all options:

```
LEVELS = ={
  easy: [2, 15], normal: [1, 10], hard: [1, 5]
}

def set_difficulty
  puts 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard'
  
  @hints, @attemps = LEVELS.fetch(user_input.to_sym) do
    puts 'Wrong input'
    set_difficulty      
  end
end
```

Note that the block of `Hash#fetch` is only called when the key is not found in the hash.

Comment: ...or  `@hints, @attempts = case user_input; when 'easy'; [2, 15]; when 'normal'; [1, 10]...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash to hold different levels and unpacking to assign multiple variables:

```
levels={
    'easy'=>[2,15],
    'normal'=>[1,10],
    'hard'=>[1,5]
}

hints,attempts=levels['easy'] #hints=2, attempts=15
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write that as follows.

```
def set_difficulty
  loop do
    print 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard: '
    case user_input
    when 'easy'
      break { hints: 2, attempts: 15 }
    when 'normal'
      break { hints: 1, attempts: 10 }
    when 'hard'
      break { hints: 1, attempts: 5 }
    else
      puts 'Wrong input'
    end
  end
end
```

```
def user_input
  gets.chomp.downcase
end
```

When `set_difficulty` is executed the following actions might take place.

```
Method displays 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard: '
User enters     'Impossible!'      
Method displays 'Wrong input'
Method displays 'Choose difficulty between easy/normal/hard: '
User enters     'normal' (or 'Normal' or 'nOrMal' or similar)       
Method returns  { hints: 1, attempts: 10 }
```

- I do not know what the method `user_input` does so I have assumed it merely accepts the user's entry, removes the return character and downcases what remains. If that's all it does there is no need for that method; simply replace `user_input` in `set_difficulty` with `gets.chomp.downcase`.
- It is common practice to use a loop in these situations, breaking out of the loop after the user has given a valid answer. Making the method recursive (as in the question) is inefficient and makes the method harder to understand.
- I have chosen to have the method return a hash (e.g., `{ hints: 1, attempts: 10 }`) rather than an array (e.g., `[1, 10]`), to make its meaning more understandable in the part of the program where it is used.
- by using `print` rather than `puts` in `print 'Choose ... : '` the user's input is displayed immediately after the space that follows the colon (rather than at the beginning of the next line).